# How to check if array of values all exist within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, filtering

I am building an object of filter data combined of categories & tags and I'd like to use this data to filter an array of content items that are objects. I've used cars as an example to illustrate this.

The filters will look like:

```
const filters = {
    categories: [
        'car',
        'van',
        'motorbike',
    ]
    tags: [
        '4x4',
        'petrol',
        'sunroof'
    ]
}
```

Then I have my content items that needs to be filtered in an array of objects:

```
const items = [
    {
        title: '2016 VW Polo',
        categories: [
            {
                title: 'Car',
                slug: 'car'
            }
        ]
        tags: [
            {
                title: 'Sunroof',
                slug: 'sunroof',
            },
            {
                title: 'Power Steering'
                slug: 'power-steering',
            },
            {
                title: 'Petrol'
                slug: 'petrol',
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        title: '2015 Audi A4',
        categories: [
            {
                title: 'Car',
                slug: 'car'
            }
        ]
        tags: [
            {
                title: 'Sunroof',
                slug: 'sunroof',
            },
            {
                title: 'Power Steering'
                slug: 'power-steering',
            },
            {
                title: 'Petrol'
                slug: 'petrol',
            },
            {
                title: '4x4'
                slug: '4x4',
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

The confusing part comes because the filtering is different. I'd need to filter this with an OR statement, so if the user filters by cars and vans, then it fetches everything with either.

Then filtering by tags is that all the items within the `filters.tags` array have to be matched within the `item.tags` array.

I've looked into it using `.forEach()`, `.filter()` and `.some()`, but I'm struggling to get this working.

Thanks!

Comment: *The confusing part comes because the filtering is different. I'd need to filter this with an OR statement, so if the user filters by cars and vans, then it fetches everything with either.* Could you explain a little bit more what is confusing you? Also, you getting a lot of downvotes because you didn't share you attempt. Even if it's almost nothing, show us your code and where you got stuck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is with syntax errors, next time please prepare a stackoverflow code snippet with proper code so anyone could copy it and answer you easily.

```js
const filters = {
    categories: [
        'car',
        'van',
        'motorbike',
    ],
    tags: [
        '4x4',
        'petrol',
        'sunroof'
    ]
}
const items = [
    {
        title: '2016 VW Polo',
        categories: [
            {
                title: 'Car',
                slug: 'car'
            }
        ],
        tags: [
            {
                title: 'Sunroof',
                slug: 'sunroof',
            },
            {
                title: 'Power Steering',
                slug: 'power-steering',
            },
            {
                title: 'Petrol',
                slug: 'petrol',
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        title: '2015 Audi A4',
        categories: [
            {
                title: 'Car',
                slug: 'car'
            }
        ],
        tags: [
            {
                title: 'Sunroof',
                slug: 'sunroof',
            },
            {
                title: 'Power Steering',
                slug: 'power-steering',
            },
            {
                title: 'Petrol',
                slug: 'petrol',
            },
            {
                title: '4x4',
                slug: '4x4',
            },
        ]
    }
]

const filtered = items.filter(({tags, categories}) => 
  // first filter by tags since it's more restrictive
  (!filters.tags.length || filters.tags.every(tag => tags.some(({slug}) => slug === tag)))
  && (!filters.categories.length || filters.categories.some(category => categories.some(({slug}) => slug === category)))
);
console.log(filtered);
```